# Laravel 5 FTP Retrieving files and directories

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to use flysystem in order to retrieve in a view all the files and directories from an FTP server.

At the moment I have a new laravel project with auth function.
In the filesystems/php file I've added the credentials for the ftp connection and int the home blade I have

```
@foreach($files as $file)
<ul>
  <li> {{ $file }}</li>
</ul>
@endforeach
```

and that is all.

Please keep in mind that I've started with laravel 3h ago.

Comment: That's some nice looking code. What exactly is the problem? Please provide a MVCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the $files as a parameter from the controller when u return a view; and then you will be able to access the $files using Laravel-blade.

```
public function index() {
        $files = ['file1', 'file2'];
        return view('home', ['files'=> $files]);
    }
```

Comment: But this will only get the files and on the server, I have directories/files public function index() {
        $files = Storage::allFiles($directory);
        return view('home', ['files'=> $files]);
}

Comment: Try to return $files; so u can check if the variable is empty or not.